# ¿ Cómo subir imagen desde VueJS a Laravel con Axios?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js

Tengo que cambiar la imagen de perfil del usuario, estoy utilizando Vuejs para tal efecto, el problema es que me pasa la imagen en `base64` y al hacer decode en el método del `myProfile` del controlador este simple o me guarda el número 1 en el campo avatar de la tabla `user` o simplemente lo pasa `null`.

Profile.vue

```
<template>
   <input type="file" name="image" @change="getImage" accept="image/*">
   <img :src="avatar" class="img-circle" width="150" />
   <a href="" v-show="loaded" class="btn btn-success" @click.prevent="updateAvatar">Upload</a>

</template>
<script>
   props: ['auth'],
data() {
    return {
        user: {},
        errorss: {},
        showMe: false,
        loaded: false,
        avatar: '',
    }
},
mounted() {
    this.user = JSON.parse(this.auth);
    this.avatar = this.user.avatar;
},
   getImage(e){
        let image = e.target.files[0];
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(image);
        reader.onload = e => {
            this.avatar = e.target.result;
        }
        this.loaded = true;
    }, 
    updateAvatar(){
        let urlAvatar = '/dashboard/avatar';
        //let value = new FormData();
        //value.append('image', this.avatar);
        const value = {
                'image': this.avatar
            }

        axios.put(urlAvatar, value)
            .then((response) => {
                let title = response.data.status;
                let body = response.data.msg;
                this.displayNotificationSuccess(title, body);
            })
            .catch((e) => {
                console.log(e.response.data);
            })
    },
</script>
```

Nota: Cuando ocupo `FormData()` avatar me pasa vacío

Al método `myProfile` ya le he hecho tantos cambios que al final lo deje así para ver como me pueden guiar.

myProfile (UserController)

```
public function myAvatar(Request $request)
{
    $file_data = $request->image;
    $avatar = Storage::putFile('public/defaults/users/avatar/', base64_decode($file_data));

    $userAvatarUpdate = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
    $userAvatarUpdate->avatar = $avatar;
    $userAvatarUpdate->update();

    return response()->json([
            'status' => 'Muy bien!',
            'msg' => 'Tu foto de perfil se actualizo.',
        ], 200);

}
```

He visto varios tutoriales pero no llego aún a la solución que se ajusta a lo que necesito.

¿Alguna idea? estoy utilizando `Laravel 5.6`, `Vuejs 2` y `Axios`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para subir imágenes con `axios` por el método `PUT`, puede realizar un "truco" y enviar por `post` desde `vue` , pero en Laravel acceder al método `PUT`. *(puede haber mejores formas de hacerlo pero ya queda para investigación :) )*

La primera recomendación para el almacenamiento de las imágenes sería seguir utilizando el `storage` pero según noto intenta almacenar directamente en la carpeta publica del proyecto lo cuál no es del todo correcto , pero para el ejemplo se seguirá con esta configuración.

Para esto en el archivo `config\filesystems.php` por defecto el `driver` de almacenamiento es `local` entonces deberá cambiar el valor de la carpeta `root` de almacenamiento para la llave local empleando `public_path` que será igual a la carpeta `public` del proyecto y dentro de esta le especificamos a Laravel que estará una carpeta `defaults`

```
'local' => [
   'driver' => 'local',
   'root' => public_path('defaults'), // miproyecto.com/public/defaults/
],
```

En el controlador simplemente podría quedar.

```
public function myAvatar(Request $request)
{
    // Verificamos si hay un file con nombre avatar
    if ($request->hasFile('avatar')) {
        // Si es así , almacenamos en la carpeta public/avatars
        // esta estará dentro de public/defaults/
       $url = $request->avatar->store('users/avatar');
        $userAvatarUpdate = User::find(auth()->id());
        /** Áctualización y 
         return JSON*/
    }
    return "Noo Llego una imagen";
}
```

**VueJs** , *(la explicación del código está  incluido)*

```
<template>
    <div>
        <input type="file" name="image" @change="getImage" accept="image/*">
        <button @click="updateAvatar">Subir Imagen</button>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {

        data(){
            return {
                imagen : null,
            }
        },
        methods  : {
            getImage(event){
                //Asignamos la imagen a  nuestra data
                this.imagen = event.target.files[0];
            },
            updateAvatar(){
                //Creamos el formData
                var data = new  FormData();
                //Añadimos la imagen seleccionada
                data.append('avatar', this.imagen);
                //Añadimos el método PUT dentro del formData
                // Como lo hacíamos desde un formulario simple _(no ajax)_
                data.append('_method', 'PUT');
                //Enviamos la petición
                axios.post('/dashboard/avatar',data)
                .then(response => {

                })
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Para acceder públicamente a las imágenes tendría la ruta

```
miproyecto.com/defaults/users/avatar/hashimage
```